# IBM i: ssh remotehost /QOpenSys/usr/bin/db2 \""select 123 from sysibm.sysdummy1"\" returns blank output

Tags: db2, open-source, ibm-midrange, openssh

I have found a nice hint from Kevin Adler:
$ ln -s /QOpenSys/usr/bin/qsh /QOpenSys/usr/bin/db2
which runs great in QSH both locally and also over ssh
https://kadler.io/2018/05/29/calling-qsh-utilities-from-pase.html#

/QOpenSys/usr/bin/db2 "select 123 from sysibm.sysdummy1"
and also
ssh remotehost  /QOpenSys/usr/bin/db2 ""select 123 from sysibm.sysdummy1""
returns the expected 123

```
    123       
  1 RECORD(S) SELECTED.
```

This is a handy shortcut, otherwise the command would have to be expressed as:
ssh remotehost /QOpenSys/usr/bin/system -eiqs ""CALL QSYS/QP0ZCALL ('/usr/bin/db2' 'select 123 from sysibm.sysdummy1')""

Yet on some hosts, even if /QOpenSys/usr/bin/db2 works fine locally, it returns blank output when being called over ssh. (no problem with other commands over ssh so far, all systems mentioned here are IBM i on 7.3 or 7.4)

Although there is a blank output from some of the hosts of ours for the /QOpenSys/usr/bin/db2 command the instructions get executed correctly.
create table, insert, delete... all of this gets done

ssh remotehost  system ""QSYS/DSPOBJD OBJ(SCO/ROB123) OBJTYPE(*FILE)""
CPF2105: Object ROB123 in SCO type *FILE not found.
$

ssh remotehost  /QOpenSys/usr/bin/db2 ""create table sco.rob123 (Number int, Name varchar(10), City varchar(10))""
$

ssh remotehost  system ""QSYS/DSPOBJD OBJ(SCO/ROB123) OBJTYPE(*FILE)""
Display Object Description - Basic                                             Page
1
5770SS1 V7R4M0  190621                                                                          REMOTEHOST   22-08-25  11:22:42 EEDS
T
Library . . . . . . . :   SCO                                      Library ASP device  . :   *SYSBAS
Library ASP group . . :   *SYSBAS
Object         Type         Attribute                  Size     Text
ROB123         *FILE        PF                        40960
* * * * *   E N D   O F   L I S T I N G   * * * * *
$

ssh remotehost  system ""DSPFD FILE(SCO/ROB123) TYPE(*ALL)"" | grep "Total records"
Total records  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :                 0
$

ssh remotehost  /QOpenSys/usr/bin/db2 ""insert into sco.rob123 values (1, 'jenda', 'crhof')""
$

ssh remotehost  system ""DSPFD FILE(SCO/ROB123) TYPE(*ALL)"" | grep "Total records"
Total records  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :                 1
$

ssh remotehost  /QOpenSys/usr/bin/db2 ""delete from sco.rob123""
$

ssh remotehost  system ""DSPFD FILE(SCO/ROB123) TYPE(*ALL)"" | grep "Total records"
Total records  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :                 0
$
ssh remotehost  /QOpenSys/usr/bin/db2 ""insert into sco.rob123 values (1, 'jenda', 'crhof')""
$
ssh remotehost  system ""DSPFD FILE(SCO/ROB123) TYPE(*ALL)"" | grep "Total records"
Total records  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :                 1
$

ssh remotehost  /QOpenSys/usr/bin/db2 ""select * from sco.rob123""
$

ssh -v remotehost  /QOpenSys/usr/bin/db2 ""select * from sco.rob123""
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/SC1/OpenSSH/etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to remotehost [10.1.1.10] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.0 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to remotehost:22 as 'user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:WOjO7zT1MIS3NeMhPq786/0GVGbZYlGXhDnFOlRpL7k
debug1: Host 'remotehost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:50
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:mP1UusmDO6fvA+67200rZHR+XC2hMZTITEejMuWZRZw
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2
-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:mP1UusmDO6fvA+67200rZHR+XC2hMZTITEejMuWZRZw
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:mP1UusmDO6fvA+67200rZHR+XC2hMZTITEejMuWZRZw
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to remotehost ([10.1.1.10]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Sending command: /QOpenSys/usr/bin/db2 "select * from sco.rob123"
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3132, received 2860 bytes, in 0.4 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 7799.9, received 7122.5
debug1: Exit status 0
$

And I keep failing to find out why the output for this particular command /QOpenSys/usr/bin/db2 on a handful of our systems is blank.
Does any one, please, have any clue?
Thank you

Comment: Is ssh turned on? It is not by default. There are a number of things that can block ssh from working properly. A call to IBM support will usually take care of this. BTW, this is not really a question that can be answered here.

Comment: What's the purpose of creating a symbolic link from "qsh" to "db2"?  That makes no sense.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show exactly what command you're running when you run db2 over ssh and it doesn't work, and exactly what output it produces. It would be helpful to run ssh with the "-v" flag to print debugging output, and include that debugging output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

it came out it was not specifically about db2 but more in general the use of
/QOpenSys/usr/bin/system (/QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/OS400/PASE/bin/system)
did not provide any output at all when called over ssh

Resolution:
The IBM /QOpenSys/usr/bin/qsh
contains at the end of the script
...
exec /QOpenSys/usr/bin/system -eiqs "CALL QSYS/QP0ZCALL ('/usr/bin/$basename' $args)"

and after omitting the "s" parameter:
exec /QOpenSys/usr/bin/system -eiq "CALL QSYS/QP0ZCALL ('/usr/bin/$basename' $args)"

all /usr/bin/... commands wrapped into /QOpenSys/usr/bin/system provide the output even when called over ssh.

So now it is time to inspect CCSIDs
( https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=utilities-pase-i-system-utility )